# Как поднять приоритет слоя Ignore Raycast?

Tags: c#, unity3d

На Terrain стоит rigitbody объект с Mesh Renderer. При перемещении его с помощью курсора мыши мы временно меняем его слой на Ignore Raycast и он частично погружается в Terrain. Вопрос: как правильно настроить слой Ignore Raycast, чтобы он отображался поверх других слоев? В списке sorting layers нужно поднять более приоритетный слой наверх или как-то по-другому?

[image: sorting_layers img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте свой новый слой, который будет ниже терейна и перемещайте объект в него :) а, чтобы настроить его "игнорирование" выберете ваш рейкастер (вероятно, на основной камере висит) и уберите этот слой из его целевых слоёв)
То какой слой с каким взаимодействует физически настраивается по пути Edit(вкладка в верхнем меню)=> Project Settings => Physics.

Однако, ваше "проваливание" скорее всего связано не со взаимодействием физических слоёв, т.к. по умолчанию оно включено между всеми из них, а с тем, что вы задаёте объекту принудительную позицию, через transform, а не физическую через его rigidbody

Comment: спасибо, вы были правы. Задал позицию через rigidbody, поменял update на fixedupdate и все стало прекрасно.